# CentOS 7: Get total and remaining hard disk capacity

Tags: bash, centos

I am making a simple script to display some information about my CentOS 7 PC, similar to the `System Information` application on Windows.

I wanted to know if there is a command which will display the total and remaining capacity of my virtual disk?

Currently, I'm aware of the `df` command which I have used in this configuration to give me the remaining capacity:

```
df -Ph | grep sda1 | awk '{print $4}' | tr -d '\n'
```

I am also aware of the `lsblk` command, which does show the total size of my virtual disc.

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   60G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0   59G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0   37G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0  3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 18.1G  0 lvm  /home
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

I can also filter the `lsblk` command via: `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE` which gives:

```
NAME             SIZE
sda               60G
├─sda1             1G
└─sda2            59G
  ├─centos-root   37G
  ├─centos-swap  3.9G
  └─centos-home 18.1G
sr0             1024M
```

I would like to know how I can filter the output to just show `60G` which is the capacity of `sda`?

I don't know anything about `awk` but I have seen it pop-up is many other responses to similar questions, so maybe this is something I need to look further into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```bash
lsblk -no SIZE /dev/sda | head -1
```

With `lsblk -n` the headings will not be printed. So if you run:

```bash
lsblk -no SIZE /dev/sda
```

The output will be something like this:

```
970.5M
970.4M
```

The first value `970.5M` is the total disk capacity of `/dev/sda`. With `head -1` it will get only the first line of the output, in this case `970.5M`. The another value `970.4M` is the capacity of `/dev/sda1` (in my case).

```bash
lsblk -no PATH,NAME,SIZE /dev/sda
#Output:
/dev/sda  sda    970.5M
/dev/sda1 └─sda1 970.4M
```

You can use the command above to specify any partition. For example, If I want to get information about `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/nvme0n1p1` I should use:

```bash
lsblk -no PATH,NAME,SIZE /dev/nvme0n1p1 /dev/sda1
#Output:
/dev/sda1      sda1      970.4M
/dev/nvme0n1p1 nvme0n1p1   260M
```

Regarding your question: **how I could display just the result of sda3** you can use this:

```bash
lsblk -no SIZE  /dev/sda3
```

Comment: Hello @user:414186 thank you for your response. This has been helpful and definitely achieved what I need. I'm looking to expand and show what the remaining space on the disk. When I run the `lsblk no NAME,SIZE /dev/sda` command, I get: `sda1 `238.5G` and further down the tree `sda3 237.3G`. Do you happen to known how I could display just the result of `sda3`

Comment: @Hymcode sure, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get **TOTAL DISK CAPACITY** one other way to do it you might find useful is with `smartctl`.

For example:

```
smartctl --scan

smartctl --xall /dev/sda

# in my case a scan results in

  Smartctl open device: /dev/sda failed: DELL or MegaRaid controller, please try adding '-d megaraid,N'

# therefore for me a    smartctl -d megaraid,0 --all /dev/bus/0       shows

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               TOSHIBA
Product:              KPM5WRUG3T84
Revision:             B322
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        3,840,755,982,336 bytes [3.84 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is resource provisioned, LBPRZ=1
Rotation Rate:        Solid State Device
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x58ce38ee20abca2d
Serial number:        
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Wed Oct 12 14:26:53 2022 EDT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported
Read Cache is:        Enabled
Writeback Cache is:   Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Percentage used endurance indicator: 4%
Current Drive Temperature:     29 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        70 C

Manufactured in week 33 of year 2019
Elements in grown defect list: 0
```

a `smartctl -d megaraid,0 --all /dev/bus/0 | grep Capacity | awk '{print $3}'` extracts `3,840,755,982,336` which you could make use of.

Check `man smartctl` for options on how to maybe have it all done with an option to smartctl instead of piping to grep and to awk.

But `smartctl` won't tell you used or remaining capacity, but I think **it would be a good way to get a trustworthy total disk capacity number**.

Also a `lshw -class disk` and `lshw -short -C disk` might interest you:

```
lshw -short -C disk
H/W path         Device        Class          Description
=========================================================
/0/2/0/2.0.0     /dev/sda      disk           3840GB PERC H740P Adp    {my one OS disk}
/0/2/0/2.1.0     /dev/sdb      disk           19TB PERC H740P Adp      {the 7 other disks as RAID-5 making 19tb volume I mount as /data}
```

Comment: also an `lshw -class disk` and `lshw -short -C disk` might interest you.